# Find properties of taskbar item in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I created a script to launch a cygwin rxvt instance with certain options, and put it in my Windows Taskbar. I want to duplicate that on another computer, but I can seem to access the original shortcut that I made. When I right-click it, I only get the options to run it or unpin it.

How can I see the shortcut properties that I put on the taskbar?

Comment: Well darn it. I unpinned it, and the thing disappeared. That sucks :P

Comment: It may still exist in the Recycle Bin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you right-click a Windows 7 taskbar item, you can then right-click the main program entry and choose Properties.

[image: right clicking the jump list]

Pinned items are shortcuts located in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. No easy do describe... When you click on a pinned shortcut, a small menu pops up. Dont rightclick that pinned shortcut but the one the one that pops up. I'm on a XP machine right now - will make a screenshot when back @ win7...