# Passing arguments to executable pinned in Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, shortcuts

I try to add `--enable-vertical-tabs` to the Chrome shortcut/pin in my Windows7 Taskbar.

Like indicated here https://superuser.com/a/234287 I edited properties of the shortcut. In the end the target is: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -enable-vertical-tabs"`

However Windows7 doesn't allow me for such a target:

```
[Window Title]
Problem with Shortcut

[Content]
The name 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --enable-vertical-tabs'
specified in the Target box is not valid. 
Make sure the path and file name are correct.

[OK]
```

Any idea how can I pass arguments to the executables pinned in Taskbar ?

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -enable-vertical-tabs" is missing a `-` character, there sould be 2 `--enable-vertical-tabs`

Comment: Good typo catch, but I have the same windows warning with the typo correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source [A list of useful Google Chrome command line switches](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/06/list-useful-google-chrome-command-line-switches/)

> If you are starting Google Chrome from a shortcut, placed on the
>   desktop, taskbar or start menu, then you can easily add command line
>   switches to it.  Just right-click the shortcut, locate Google Chrome
>   there, right-click on it and select Properties.
>
> The Shortcut tab should open up automatically. It displays the load
>   path of the browser in the target field. **At the end of the field,
>   after the closing ", add a space, and then the command line switches
>   you want to use.**
>
> Add another space between each command line switch if you want to use
>   multiple ones.

Your shortcut is malformed. You have:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -enable-vertical-tabs"
```

The options to `chrome` should be **outside** of the `"`s:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --enable-vertical-tabs
```

Note also the option should be `--enable-vertical-tabs` **not** `-enable-vertical-tabs`